# Is this translation request off-topic here?

Tags: discussion

This question [Kiel traduki Esperante tiun ĉi ludkarton?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/kiel-traduki-esperante-tiun-%c4%89i-ludkarton) requests a translation of the text of a playing card, not any specific word or phrase. Is it outside the topic for this site?

Comment: I suppose it is okay since we aren't overwhelmed in questions atm. But this question does have lower reuse value compared to others as @kiamlaluno said.

Answer (score 0):

I understood the question to be "how do you translate the name of this monster" - which I chose not to answer but for other reasons. I do think it's essentially off topic and if our community is to have any value, we will come up with some guidelines about this.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it off-topic for the fact of asking how to translate in Esperanto a name of an imaginary creature that is not even as common as dragons, griffins, or unicorns.

It is an invented word created specifically for a playing card game, and I don't feel the question is going to help future users.